# c++ display more than one image gid+

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, gdi+

im trying to display image when left mouse button is down.
i can display the image but if the left mouse button is down again than the older image would be deleted.
here is my code
display image function

```
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
    Image shot(L"RegularShots.png");
    graphics.DrawImage(&shot, pt.x, pt.y);
}
```

left mouse button down

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    RegularShots=0;
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
    break;
```

wm_paint

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    OnPaint(hdc, hWnd, 1);
    if(RegularShots==0)
    {
        RegularShot(hdc, hWnd);
    }
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

anyideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a collection (array / vector etc.) of coordinates that is added to each time the mouse button is pressed - and then when rendering in WM_PAINT, draw an image at each of these locations.

Comment: i thought of that. the problem is how to store the coordinates in array when the program runs i don't know how many times the left mouse button gonna be down

Comment: That's where vector comes in - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs%28v=VS.80%29.aspx.